# Disabling mouseReleased function on a JPanel

Tags: java

How can i disable a `mouseReleased` function in a `JPanel`?
Like it keeps the mouse pressed when it is in the JPanel but it will be released after getting the mouse off the JPanel?

Comment: what listener are you using?

Comment: im using mouseListener